Calling a specific column from a structure with fields
I'm building something using the octopus agile tariff API. My code downloads a structure from the API with the price per kWh of electricity. However, the energy costs are in a structure with fields and when I try to index the value_inc_vat column, I only get the first result. How do I retrieve the entire column?
clc
current_date = string(datetime('today','Format','uuuu-MM-dd'))
yesterdays_date = string(datetime('yesterday','Format','uuuu-MM-dd'))

api_url = append('https://api.octopus.energy/v1/products/AGILE-24-04-03/electricity-tariffs/E-1R-AGILE-24-04-03-C/standard-unit-rates/?period_from=', yesterdays_date ,'T22:00Z&period_to=' , current_date ,'T23:59Z');

api_call = webread(api_url)

costs = api_call.results
value_inc_vat = api_call.results.value_inc_vat


To get all of a field's values from a struct array as a single array you need to group the outputs with square brackets
value_inc_vat = [api_call.results(:).value_inc_vat];

Use square brackets here because it's a numeric array, for non-numeric data you could do the same with { curly braces } to get a cell array.

Use:
costs = {api_call(:).results.value_inc_vat}'


Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. Also do note that ' is the complex conjugate transpose, not the regular one. Finally, to outsiders it is unclear why you'd need this as a cell, rather than a regular array (using [] instead of {}). Could you please elaborate on that?
